# Install mysql2 package manually - Sequelize-cli db:migrate

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

On using the command sequelize-cli db:migrate I am getting the error:

ERROR: Please install mysql2 package manually.

I could see mysql2 in the package.json file from the very beginning though still I tried to install it again.

The problem is I ran this command before on the same project and it ran successfully but I cannot get why it's giving such error now. I have tried all the commands to install mysql2 given in a related question but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete node_modules, and package-lock.json. and then install again "npm i"